# i want that if a user come on page so that popup will auto comes up

Tags: jquery, html

i want that if a user come on page so that popup will auto comes up.

i am using this code but this is working on hover i want that it will automatically come up.

```
jQuery(function($) {

    $("a.topopup").click(function() {
        loading(); // loading
        setTimeout(function(){ // then show popup, deley in .5 second
            loadPopup(); // function show popup 
        }, 500); // .5 second
        return false;
    });

    /* event for close the popup */
    $("div.close").hover(
        function() {
            $('span.ecs_tooltip').show();
        },
        function () {
            $('span.ecs_tooltip').hide();
        }
    );

    $("div.close").click(function() {
        disablePopup();  // function close pop up
    });

    $(this).keyup(function(event) {
        if (event.which == 27) { // 27 is 'Ecs' in the keyboard
            disablePopup();  // function close pop up
        }   
    });

    $("div#backgroundPopup").click(function() {
        disablePopup();  // function close pop up
    });

    $('a.livebox').click(function() {
        alert('Hello World!');
    return false;
    });

     /************** start: functions. **************/
    function loading() {
        $("div.loader").show();  
    }
    function closeloading() {
        $("div.loader").fadeOut('normal');  
    }

    var popupStatus = 0; // set value

    function loadPopup() { 
        if(popupStatus == 0) { // if value is 0, show popup
            closeloading(); // fadeout loading
            $("#toPopup").fadeIn(0500); // fadein popup div
            $("#backgroundPopup").css("opacity", "0.7"); // css opacity, supports IE7, IE8
            $("#backgroundPopup").fadeIn(0001); 
            popupStatus = 1; // and set value to 1
        }   
    }

    function disablePopup() {
        if(popupStatus == 1) { // if value is 1, close popup
            $("#toPopup").fadeOut("normal");  
            $("#backgroundPopup").fadeOut("normal");  
            popupStatus = 0;  // and set value to 0
        }
    }
    /************** end: functions. **************/
}); // jQuery End**
```

Html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Creating Popup Div | istockphp.com</title>
<link href="style/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="#" class="topopup">Click Here Trigger</a>

    <div id="toPopup"> 

        <div class="close"></div>
        <span class="ecs_tooltip">Press Esc to close <span class="arrow"></span></span>
        <div id="popup_content"> <!--your content start-->
            <p>
            Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, 
            feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi 
            vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, 
            commodo Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique 
            senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, 
            feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. </p>
            <br />
            <p>
            Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi 
            vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, 
            commodo Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. </p>
            <p align="center"><a href="#" class="livebox">Click Here Trigger</a></p>
        </div> <!--your content end-->

    </div> <!--toPopup end-->

    <div class="loader"></div>
    <div id="backgroundPopup"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Please Help me .

Comment: You don't appear to call loadPopup() inside the enclosure, you just set it up to execute after a timeout on the click of a.topopup;

Comment: it does not auto popup?

Comment: Not if you don't tell it to; you need to call loadPopup() if you want it to show. Is it working if you click where it says "click here to trigger"?

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell, the trigger for the popup is a click with the mouse `($("a.topopup").click(function()...and so on)`.

But what you actually want is, that the popup get's displayed once the page has loaded. I would try the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        loading(); // loading
        setTimeout(function(){ // then show popup, deley in .5 second
        loadPopup(); // function show popup 
        }, 500); // .5 second
        return false;
    });
```

[Here](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) the information from the jQuery documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Just call `loadPopup()` when the page loads.

```
var popupStatus = 0; // set value

function loadPopup() { 
    if(popupStatus == 0) { // if value is 0, show popup
        closeloading(); // fadeout loading
        $("#toPopup").fadeIn(0500); // fadein popup div
        $("#backgroundPopup").css("opacity", "0.7"); // css opacity, supports IE7, IE8
        $("#backgroundPopup").fadeIn(0001); 
        popupStatus = 1; // and set value to 1
    }   
}

loadPopup();
```